# Python function's __dict__

Tags: python, python-3.x, namespaces

I know functions objects have a `__dict__`. Few times this is used to add attributes to the function. Some people even use it to add anotations to the function.

My doubt is the following. If a have:

```
def foo():
   a = 2
   return
```

Where is **"a"** stored?

I make this question because I was expecting to find it in the `__dict__` of **foo**, but now I know this is not the purpose of a function's `__dict__`.

If functions are instance objects of the class **function**, and the namespace of an object is defined by its `__dict__`. What is the namespace of **a**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `a` doesn't exist when the `foo` is defined, it is dynamically created when the `foo` is run, that is why it is not stored as an attribute of the function. Since `a` exists in the local scope of `foo`, you can see it with the `locals` function:

```
>>> def foo():
...     a = 22
...     print(locals())

>>> foo()
{'a': 22}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer.